# Javascript loop through images attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` on my website which contains a number of images. I'm trying to get the `onclick` attribute of each of the images inside said `div`.

```
<div class="hoi">
    <img src="" onclick="alert('hoi')"/>
    <img src="" onclick="alert('hoi')"/>
</div>
```

I've tried the following Javascript code:

```
var count = $(".hoi img").length;

for(var i = 0; i <= count; i++){
    alert($('.hoi').find('img').getAttribute('onclick'));
}
```

But I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Here is a fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/4Lhn0u87/7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lhn0u87/8/

Comment: Use `find('img').attr('onclick')` or `find('img')[0].getAttribute('onclick')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method called `getAttribute()` in jQuery object, you have [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr). [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) is a dom api method.

```
$('.hoi img').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('onclick'))
})
```

Also to iterate through a set of elements you can use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each).

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick is a event you can't use it as a data-attribute.use some other.
Here is the working code:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/4Lhn0u87/17/

```
$('.hoi img').each(function(){
$(this).on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).attr('data-onclick'));
})
})
```

I have change onclick to data-onclick and removed alert('hoi') and placed image_1 and image_2 for understanding